# GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, smtp, smtpclient

I have code that sends mail with SMTP client but when sending I get this strange error.

My app server communicates with the mail server on an internal thread. Mail is sent from the Linux server itself with a command, but I can't do it with SMTP from the code. I am sharing my code and error. What is this error related to?

```cs
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.0.188.30", 587);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mailtest@company.local", "Paris2024!");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("mailtest@company.local"), new MailAddress(user.Email));
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = body;
await client.SendMailAsync(message);
```

> Error : GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.
> Minor code may provide more information (Cannot find KDC for realm
> "company.local").